# Zend_ProgressBar: is there a good example / tutorial on how to use it?

Tags: zend-framework, progress-bar

I'm trying to use Zend_ProgressBar in my project (made using MVC in Zend Framework). 
Unfortunately, I cannot find any full example on how to use it. Zend Programmer's Reference Guide has only some code snippets, which are not enough for me. Basically, I don't know how  incorporate  Zend_ProgressBar with some action in a controller and associated views.

Does anyone know of the simples example or tutorial of zend application that uses Zend_ProgressBar?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have created some demos for the case that the documentation may not be sufficient:

http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/standard/trunk/demos/Zend/ProgressBar/

Comment: Unfortunately, the link is broken